# how to set a position marker in a tracking movie in matlab

Tags: matlab, tracking, marker

I have a movie with bugs walking around an arena. I am tracking them all simultaneously. I would like to set a certain point in the arena that is filmed, that tracked bugs trigger when they pass through it.
In the end, I would like to observe which bug crossed the marker, how many times, and when it happened. 
Thanks

Comment: You may want to have a look at this example http://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detecting-cars-in-a-video-of-traffic.html about detecting cars in a video

Answer (score 0):

It's worth for you to have a look at the Computer Vision toolbox, in Matlab.

See [this example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/tracking-cars-using-optical-flow.html#zmw57dd0e6800).

Comment: perhaps I didn't make myself clear. I already have the tracking part working. I now would like to add a marker to the video, such as a line, that collects information about the bugs that ran through it. Say I place the line in certain (x,y) coordinates, I would like to know which of the bugs that i track passed it and when (what frame). Hope this is clearer

Comment: you have the (X,Y) of each bugs, you have the (X,Y) of a line or another graphical object, you have the frame index in the video. Where is the problem?

Comment: how do i add the graphical object?